# Copy specific sheet names from range

Tags: excel, vba

I need help and I'm hoping someone here can help me :)

I have a workbook that runs some reports from Avaya CMS. It runs the report and creates a new sheet for each persons name on the MAIN sheet. << This part works wonderfully.

My issue is I cannot figure out how to use that range of names on the MAIN sheet to select only those specific sheets and then copy them to a new workbook.. There's 2 other hidden sheets as well.. Which is why I think using the range of names is easier but I'm open to anything at this point.

Here's an screeshot of what it looks like :

[image]

Sorry, I couldn't figure out how to upload the workbook here but the image should, hopefully, be good enough. Thank you for your time and help!

Here's an image with the hidden sheets.
[image: Here's an image with the hidden sheets.]

I need it to exclude the first 3 sheets/

And here's the code:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim sheetArray() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0

    For Each c In MainSheet.Range("A2:A20").Cells
        ReDim Preserve sheetArray(0 To i)
        sheetArray(i) = c.Value
        i = i + 1
    Next
    Sheets(sheetArray).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA Selecting multiple sheets using a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26861958/vba-selecting-multiple-sheets-using-a-range)

Comment: How the hell did you find that?! I've been looking for something like that for 3 days now... smh

Comment: What I meant to say... Thank you :)

Comment: Googled for "vba select multiple sheets" --> 4ᵗʰ link --> bingo.

Comment: I guess I was making my searches more complicated that it needed to be

Comment: Hmm. I keep getting Subscript out of Range on "Sheets(sheetArray).Select"

Comment: That means one of the sheets named in the range does not exist. Go through the code step by step using F8 and check the values of the array.

Comment: The sheet names come from the range on MAIN.. I stepped though it and it seems to go through all the sheets, plus 12 more... I also tried adding the MAIN and other 2 hidden sheets to the range and it still errors.

Comment: Please [edit] your original question add the **exact** code you are using right now into the question. And probably you should take the code from the answer that has 3 up-votes instead of the code of the answer that has 0 votes?

Comment: Well you are using `A2:A20` but there is only valid sheet names in `A2:A4`. So use the correct range.

Comment: Ugh. It was something stupid.

Comment: That worked... And that explains why it did it an extra 12 times... smh.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub move_Sheets()

Dim mSH As Worksheet
Set mSH = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main")

Dim shArray() As String
Dim i As Integer
i = mSH.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
ReDim Preserve shArray(0 To i - 2)

For a = 2 To i
    shArray(a - 2) = mSH.Range("A" & a).Value
Next a

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(shArray).Move

End Sub
```

Comment: This also works! After I fixed the range... I got the original code working.. I was dumb and overlooked it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, sheetIndex As Long
    Dim SheetName As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main")

        'Last row of column where the names appears
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    'Loop the column from row 2 to last row
        For i = 2 To LastRow

            'Set Sheet name
            SheetName = .Range("A" & i).Value

            'Check if the sheet with the SheetName exists
            If DoesSheetExists(SheetName) Then
                'Insert the code to code
                sheetIndex = Workbooks("Book2").Sheets.Count
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).Copy After:=Workbooks("Book2").Sheets(sheetIndex)
            Else

            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub

Function DoesSheetExists(SheetName As String) As Boolean

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetName)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not ws Is Nothing Then DoesSheetExists = True

End Function
```

Comment: Yea I did have to add a LastRow cause the list will probably change. Thank you for your reply!