# Macro to select multiple tabs not working

Tags: excel, vba, select, tabs

Worksheets(x).Select (False)

this macro code was intended to select multiple tabs (x) from # to ##.  This no longer works and gives a 1004 error.  I have seen many people asking online having the same issue but none of those were answered satisfactorily. hopefully someone can help?
Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26861958/vba-selecting-multiple-sheets-using-a-range

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBA Selecting multiple sheets using a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26861958/vba-selecting-multiple-sheets-using-a-range)

Answer (score 1):

Your example is not very well chose because (x) can't stand for "from # to ##". The syntax of that expression is of critical importance.

`Worksheets(1).Select` will select the first worksheet, counting tabs from the left. The previously selected sheet will be unselected. You can make that instruction implicit by specifying `Worksheets(1).Select True`. You can also reverse that instruction with `Worksheets(1).Select False`. The new selection will be added to the previously existing.

You can specify several worksheets, like `Sheets(Array(1, 3, 4)).Select`. Here the tabs 1, 3 and 4 will be selected. The tabs need to be specified in an array and you can quote names, as strings, instead of numbers but still as an array. You can replace the array with a variable containing an array.

And you can add *True* or *False* to the selection within the same meaning as explained above. I hope this explanation solves your problem.